# How do you embed windows media player audio in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, media, audio-player, internet-radio

Hi I need help with embedding windows media player audio in a wordpress site for a live radio stream using html or just a simple source code !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Please post what you have tried, what errors you encountered while doing so, etc..  Generally you aren't going to get the work just handed to you.

Comment: have you looked into html5 audio tags? it's pretty straight forward

Answer (score 0):

I mean there's 5 pages of Plugin results for the search term `Audio`: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/audio/

One of those is bound to help you out. I've also seen premium themes with built in audio post type formatting.

You could also use an HTML widget or the Text Editor on a page/post and use a basic HTML5 [`<audio>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) tag:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/my-music.wav" type="audio/wav">
    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```